# What Grails Version is Needed for WeCeem

Tags: grails, weceem

I have literally tried every possible combination that I can think of to install weceem as a plugin into an existing sample application that I'm practicing grails development on, nothing has worked. I've tried all the recommended repositories in various combinations and that did not work. I have tried several versions of grails between 2.3.7 to 2.4.2 and cannot get it to work. I followed the documentation on the site for installing the plugin and was not able to get it to successfully work.

Is there another CMS that runs in grails applications that's worth looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from July Antonicheva, this is what I did to get it working:

1) Switched to NetBeans IDE
2) I downloaded version 7 of Java (Oracle)
3) Created a brand new project based on Grails 2.3.7
4) Added weceem plugin and made some adjustments to Datasource.groovy to add MySQL support

Everything is working fine now without errors. The current version of weceem needs Grails 2.3.7 and Java 7 in order for it work. I mentioned that I switched to NetBeans IDE, I found it to be a little easier to work with than eclipse and for some reason it seemed to run a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is one (indeed a new one) called [**spud cms**](http://grails.org/plugin/spud-cms) which can be used. BTW, what was the error you were getting while using weceem plugin?

The plugin should be defined in the plugin section in `BuildConfig.groovy` as:

```
plugins {
    compile ":weceem:1.2"
}
```

Comment: The error was "Resolve Error Dependencies...ckeditor:zip:3.6.6.1.0". I was getting the errors for other dependencies which i kept upgrading to the latest versions, but that ckeditor error I could not get rid of after hours of trying. I'm going to take a look at Spud, i glanced it quickly just now and it looks like it's still in early stages.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin should work for version of grails-2.3.x (version 2.3.7 should be ok -- the demo application for weceem you can find there https://github.com/jCatalog/weceem-app ); the version of grails-2.4 is not supported yet in weceem-1.2 (but should be supported in new release that is planned in month or two). Please, provide the error stack-trace, to see the problem.

Comment: I tried adding it as a plugin after downgrading the grails version in the practice app and it didn't work. I literally spent hours trying to get it working and Googling errors. Maybe i'll revisit on the next version release and see if some of the bugs have been worked out.

Comment: Okay, in case if you decide to try/use plugin one more time and have some problems you can contact me directly.